# tor adds its own private_key for hidden_service, hijacking my custom .onion

Tags: configuration, onion-services, private-key

If I delete every key from my

```
/srv/www/html
```

directory and then add my own shalot generated private to the same directory, upon tor start, it adds it's own keys to the directory, and then hijacks the hostname file with it's own .onion url.

Attempts to add my own hostname file and set immutable bit, only makes it so tor won't start.

```
# cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/hidden_service

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name lqpoku4u5v5law5d.onion;
        root /srv/www/html/;
        index index.html index.php;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        charset     utf-8;


        #location / {
        #        try_files $uri $uri/ @uwsgi;
        #}

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

dir and permissions before tor start:

```
/srv/www/html# ls -l
total 16
drwx------ 2 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 13 23:08 authorized_clients
-rwx------ 1 www-data www-data   63 Oct 14 00:23 hostname.old
-rwx------ 1 www-data www-data   88 Oct 13 14:58 index.html
-rwx------ 1 www-data www-data  887 Oct 14 16:26 private_key
```

dir and permissions following tor start:

```
/srv/www/html# ls -l
total 28
drwx------ 2 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 13 23:08 authorized_clients
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data   63 Oct 14 17:20 hostname
-rwx------ 1 www-data www-data   63 Oct 14 00:23 hostname.old
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data   64 Oct 14 17:20 hs_ed25519_public_key
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data   96 Oct 14 17:20 hs_ed25519_secret_key
-rwx------ 1 www-data www-data   88 Oct 13 14:58 index.html
-rwx------ 1 www-data www-data  887 Oct 14 16:26 private_key
```

torrc edits:

HiddenServiceDir /srv/www/html/
HiddenServiceVersion 3
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80

How do I add my own .onion address so that tor doesn't hijack my hostname file?

My key is known good and did work before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember `shallot` is used to generate custom keys and service names for version 2 of hidden services and you are requesting:

```
HiddenServiceVersion 3
```

Remove the above mentioned line and it should work.

For version 3 name generation you can use `mkp224o`.

Comment: You nailed it.
I made the change earlier and forget.